# Spurious resonance in microstrip transmission line

Tags: microwave, microstrip, vna

We were trying to study the broadband response of a microstrip line on a 1.5mm thick Rogers AD1000 substrate whose Dk=10.7 and loss tangent=0.0023 at 10 GHz. The trace width is 1.2 mm.  The S21 is expected to be near 0 dBm throughout the frequency range. However, there is a spurious resonance near 5.5 GHz, and the S21 deteriorates again after 10 GHz. What are the possible causes of and remedies to this problem?[image] [image]

Comment: Is your microstrip becoming a patch antenna?

Comment: Let's see a photo of the ground soldering on the other side of the board